# Google bigQuery split column

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, google-bigquery

I am using google bigQuery to analyze the amazon book review dataset. The dataset has a 'helpful' column which looks like this: 'helpful' :[0, 0] where the first element is a 'yes' vote and the second is a 'total' vote.

When I upload the data inn bigQuery, it splits the column into two rows because it does not support the array format.
[bigQuery screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj1jb.png).
Using the 'apply series' method in python pandas I can split the helpful column into two columns- 'helpful vote' and 'total vote':
[jupyter notebook screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgBp1.png)

If I write this query to do the same in BQ:

```
SELECT TA1.reviewerID, TA1.helpful AS yes, TA2.helpful AS total
FROM table_name as TA1

LEFT JOIN table_name as TA2
ON TA1.reviewerID = TA2.reviewerID and TA2.helpful != TA1.helpful
GROUP BY TA1.reviewerID
```

I get the following error:
Error: (L1:27): Expression 'TA1.helpful' is not present in the GROUP BY list.

The same query works in my sqlite3. What am I doing wrong in BQ?

Thanks,

Comment: this seems like an interesting dataset, would you be able to share it?

Comment: @Felipe [link](http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/)

Comment: Thanks! Now, if you have it loaded in BigQuery and it's open data, you could share the dataset publicly. It would also make much easier to answer questions like this :).  https://twitter.com/felipehoffa/status/761635507080081408

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  reviewerID, 
  helpful[OFFSET(0)] AS helpfulVote, 
  helpful[OFFSET(1)] AS totalVote 
FROM table_name
```

You can test it with dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH table_name AS (
  SELECT 'A' AS reviewerID, [0,0] AS helpful UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS reviewerID, [0,2] AS helpful
)
SELECT 
  reviewerID, 
  helpful[OFFSET(0)] AS helpfulVote, 
  helpful[OFFSET(1)] AS totalVote 
FROM table_name
```

See more for [Accessing Array Elements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#accessing-array-elements)

In case if for some reason you are still using BigQuery Legacy SQL, you can use below version (meantime see [Migrating from legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) to Standard SQL as this is a preferred version to use)

```sql
#legacydSQL
SELECT 
  reviewerID,
  MIN(helpful) WITHIN RECORD AS helpfulVote,
  MAX(helpful) WITHIN RECORD AS totalVote
FROM table_name
```

> The same query works in my sqlite3. What am I doing wrong in BQ?

And finally, if you want your original query to work/fixed - see below and read more about how [GROUP BY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#groupby) works

```sql
#legacydSQL
SELECT 
  TA1.reviewerID as reviewerID, 
  MIN(TA1.helpful) AS yes, 
  MAX(TA2.helpful) AS total
FROM table_name   as TA1
LEFT JOIN table_name   as TA2
ON TA1.reviewerID = TA2.reviewerID -- and TA2.helpful != TA1.helpful
GROUP BY TA1.reviewerID
```